# How can I return the image inside the screen if was outside the screen using onTouch?

Tags: android

I have an image and that image can be moved by touching. Everything is working, but I want to make this image cannot be outside of the screen. Here is my trying:

**Code**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.layout_foreground_image_view_533) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return true;
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (v.getX() < 0)
                v.setX(0);
            else if (v.getX() + v.getWidth() > displayMetrics.widthPixels)
                v.setX(displayMetrics.widthPixels - v.getWidth());
            else
                v.setX(event.getRawX() - (float) v.getWidth() / 2);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code will check if the image was less than 0 and will return it to 0. But I want the image cannot to be outside the screen ever, because if you try the code you will notice there is vibration.

Comment: Add some visuals for more understanding

Comment: @KARUNESHPALEKAR Solved, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.layout_foreground_image_view_533) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return true;
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            //For Width
            if (event.getRawX() - (float) v.getWidth() / 2 < 0)
                v.setX(0);
            else if (event.getRawX() + (float) v.getWidth() / 2 > displayMetrics.widthPixels)
                v.setX(displayMetrics.widthPixels - v.getWidth());
            else
                v.setX(event.getRawX() - (float) v.getWidth() / 2);
            //For Height
            if (event.getRawY() - (float) v.getHeight() / 2 < 0)
                v.setY(0);
            else if (event.getRawY() + (float) v.getHeight() / 2 > displayMetrics.heightPixels)
                v.setY(displayMetrics.heightPixels - v.getHeight());
            else
                v.setY(event.getRawY() - (float) v.getHeight() / 2);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change? Why did you change it? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68881047/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).